# Update to v2.10.1 causing layout to be messed up

Tags: update, debugging, navee

I updated EE to the latest version including all add-ons (Wygwam, Navee, Channel Images). For some reason the layout of most pages is messed up.

There must obviously be some code update in this version that is preventing something from displaying correctly.

I notice any page that only has one segment in the url appears fine. All multi-segment url's have messed up layouts (98% of the site).

Update: It appears to have something to do with the Navee crumbs. This is the code i am using.

```
{exp:navee:custom_crumbs wrap_type="none" backspace="2" spacer="&nbsp; > " no_last_spacer="true"}{if link != ""}<a href="{link}" title="{text}">{text}</a>{if:else}{text}{/if} {spacer}
{/exp:navee:custom_crumbs}
```

Is there something not right about this? It was previously working fine!

Comment: I'd start by looking at the source code of your rendered pages, and finding what markup is borked or missing, then find where that markup is generated in your templates.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my post and found it to be the Navee crumbs.. But what is the problem with the code exactly?

Comment: ZEDG, please add your last comment as an answer so you can give it the tick and help the site promote answered questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the backspace="2" was causing the issue. Maybe Navee updated their code so it was no longer required.